# Read lists of lists and if four elements of consecutive sublists are same thrice then concatenate 5th element of sublists to string

Tags: python, list

Read a list of lists, checks if four elements are the same in three consecutive sublists, and if so, concatenates the fifth element of those sublists to a string and it should keep other existing sublists.

Input list of lists:

```
 lists_of_lists = 
 [['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'id', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'distanceStdDev', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'value', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 0],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 0],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'source', 5]]
```

Expected New list of lists:

```
new_list = [['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'id', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'distanceStdDev', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'value', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,0,0'],['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'source', 5]]
```

Python code I've tried is:

```
def process_lists(input_lists):
    result_string = ""
    new_list_of_lists = []

    for i in range(len(input_lists) - 2):
        sublist1 = input_lists[i]
        sublist2 = input_lists[i + 1]
        sublist3 = input_lists[i + 2]

        if sublist1[:4] == sublist2[:4] == sublist3[:4]:
            result_string += sublist1[-1]
            new_list_of_lists.append(sublist1)

    return result_string, new_list_of_lists
```

Comment: what is the expected value of string?

Comment: last elements of sublists in this case: '5,0,0'

Comment: how the result list is calculated? why the sublist containing 0 is not there? (it has 4 matching elements with other lists)

Comment: It is there ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,0,0']

Comment: If I understood correctly, you could first sort your main list according to the first foir elements on the sublists (with `key = lambda sublist: sublist[:4])` ), then use `itertools.groupby` with the same key.

Comment: This one-liner gets close to what you asked for: `from itertools import groupby; list(k + [','.join(str(i[-1]) for i in g)] for k, g in groupby(input_lists, key=lambda x: x[:4]))`. But note that it converts *all* final int values to strings, and also merges *all* consecutive duplicates (not just sets of three).

Comment: @Swifty Pre-sorting the list could break the original grouping. I'm guessing the real input consists of many subsets like the one in the question, so the order probably matters.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote some caveats at the end of my answer, which I'll update when more information is given. I guess the sorting is unwelcome indeed, and divmodding the groups' lengths by 3 will take care of the grouping specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the sublists according to their first four element (be sure to sort the main list first, since groupby operates on consecutive elements):

```
from itertools import groupby

def first_four_elements(sublist):
    return sublist[:4]

lists_of_lists.sort(key=first_four_elements)
grouped_lists = groupby(lists_of_lists, key=first_four_elements)

final_list = [ [*key, ','.join([str(sublist[-1]) for sublist in group])] for key, group in grouped_lists]
```

Output:

```
[
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'distanceStdDev', '5'], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'id', '5'], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,0,0'], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'source', '5'], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'value', '5']
]
```

Caveats: compared to your expected output,

- the sublists have been reordered due to the sort.
- the single value have been turned to strings: if this is unwelcome, a test on the group length can fix that.
- it concatenates ALL consecutive sublists; once again, if only groups of 3 are to be merged, treatment of the group length can take care of that.

Here's a 2nd version, without the sorting; furthermore, it only merges consecutive groups of 3 similar sublists:

```
from itertools import groupby

final_list = []
for key, group in groupby(lists_of_lists, key=lambda sl: sl[:4]):
    group = list(group)
    threes, singles = divmod(len(group), 3)
    for i in range(threes):
        final_list.append([*key, ','.join([str(sublist[-1]) for sublist in group[3*i: 3*i+3]])])
    final_list.extend(group[3*threes:])
```

Example:

```
lists_of_lists = [
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'id', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'distanceStdDev', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'value', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 5],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 0],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 0],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 1],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'source', 5]
]

final_list = [
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'id', 5], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'distanceStdDev', 5], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'value', 5], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', '5,0,0'],
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'indexAdditionalSignList', 1], 
 ['RoadAttributesExtended', 'trafficSignsPreview', 'validTrailerSpeedLimits', 'source', 5]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a Python function that checks if four elements are the same in three consecutive sublists and concatenates the fifth element of those sublists to a string while keeping other existing sublists intact.
Replace the input_list variable with your actual list of lists. This function iterates through the input list and checks for three consecutive sublists where the first four elements are the same. If found, it concatenates the fifth element of those sublists into a string and appends it to the result. Otherwise, it keeps the other sublists intact:

```
def concatenate_sublists(lst):
    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst) - 2:
        if len(lst[i]) >= 5 and len(lst[i+1]) >= 5 and len(lst[i+2]) >= 5:
            if lst[i][:4] == lst[i+1][:4] == lst[i+2][:4]:
                concatenated_str = lst[i][4] + lst[i+1][4] + lst[i+2][4]
                result.append(concatenated_str)
                i += 3
            else:
                result.append(lst[i])
                i += 1
        else:
            result.append(lst[i])
            i += 1
    
    
    while i < len(lst):
        result.append(lst[i])
        i += 1

    return result

# Example list of lists
input_list = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'A'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'B'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'C'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'D'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'E'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'F'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'G'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'H'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'I'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'J'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'K'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'L'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'M'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'N'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'O'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'P'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'Q'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'R'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'S'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'T'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'U'],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 'V']
]


result_list = concatenate_sublists(input_list)
print(result_list)
```

Comment: This doesn't even work with your own input list, let alone the one provided by the OP. If you look at the OP's expected output, you will see that your result is completely different. I suggest you have a rethink and try again.